# Unable to find XPath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here is my DOM structure.

```
<td class="status">
        <span id="tgtFCell10"><img src="/saas/v389/images/check.png"></span>
        <img src="/saas/v389/images/fm_meta.png" onmouseover="pnFieldMeta.show(this,event,FieldmapUtil.genMeta({"dt":"string","parent":"JournalEntry","updateable":true,"filterable":true,"uniqueName":"JournalEntry_tranId","nullable":true,"precision":256,"name":"JournalEntry_tranId","displayParentName":"JournalEntry","scale":0,"label":"JournalEntry_tranId"}))" onmouseout="pnFieldMeta.hide(this)">           
</td>
<td class="name"></td>
```

I want to find the xpath for the element using name value. My current code is

```
//tbody[@id='tgtFieldMapsTBody']/tr[1]/td/img[contains(@onmouseover,'JournalEntry_tranId')]/../following-sibling::*
```

But I am looking for a better answer which will check for exactness and not some super-set.I need a option where I can **equate** the string rather than using **contains**. If I have a case where there are two values **JournalEntry_tranId** and **JournalEntry_tranId_value**, then this will fail.Kindly help.

Comment: Along with the `xpath` you tried can you consider updating us which element are you trying identify? Thanks

Comment: Wan to find the immediate next td element of the parent

Comment: In that case why don't you simply try to locate the next `td` element instead of locating the previous `td` element & then moving to `following-sibling` ? Can you consider updating the HTML DOM to contain the next `td` element? Thanks

Comment: That is not possible as the next td element doesn't contain any unique identification. Updated HTML DOM.

Comment: Can you consider providing the required info for SO volunteers to look into your question to help you out? Thanks

Comment: Please let me know what else info you need. Thanks!

Comment: Seems the HTML DOM you provided is incorrect. The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</img>". Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB, `<img>` element should not have closing tag

Comment: @live2learn, do you want to get `<td class="name"></td>` based on `'JournalEntry_tranId'` substring?

Comment: @Andersson You are correct, the end tag for <img> element is forbidden. Thanks

Comment: @Andersson you are correct. Kindly let me know.

Comment: I apologize if the question is unclear. I need a option where I can **equate** the string rather than using **contains**. If I have a case where there are two values **JournalEntry_tranId** and **JournalEntry_tranId_value**, then this will fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
//tbody[@id='tgtFieldMapsTBody']/tr/td[img[contains(@onmouseover,'JournalEntry_tranId')]]/following-sibling::*
```

if you are looking an optional for (`/../`), then this should work.

Comment: I apologize if the question is unclear. I need a option where I can **equate** the string rather than using **contains**. If I have a case where there are two values **JournalEntry_tranId** and **JournalEntry_tranId_value**, then this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains()` you just need to include the starting and ending double quotes around it to get the exact match you want.

```
//tbody[@id='tgtFieldMapsTBody']/tr[1]/td/img[contains(@onmouseover,'\"JournalEntry_tranId\"')]/../following-sibling::*
```